# AWS API gateway: Custom domain supporting multiple Http APIs

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, custom-domain, aws-http-api

I have created two lambda functions

- register
- login

and both of them are getting triggered from respective "Http APIs" in the API gateway. I have set up the stage for both of them as prod. Now I want to call them using my custom subdomain e.g prodapi.mydomain.com by setting the path as "v1"

- prodapi.mydomain.com/v1/register
- prodapi.mydomain.com/v1/login

I am able to achieve it for a single API but when I try to do API mapping for the other one using the same path, it doesn't allow that and says "ApiMapping key already exists for this domain name".
Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

can you share the endpoint url, before adding the subdomain, and after adding the subdomain
And can you explain your endpoints, how it should look like before adding the subdomain and after

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)